# Removing elements from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Consider the array `a= [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. Now suppose I want to remove all the 2s in this array in python. So I apply `a.remove(2)`. However the result which comes out is `[1, 3, 1, 2, 3]`, i.e the only first 2 is removed. How can I remove all the 2s which appear in an array? In general, given an array and an element p, how can I remove all the elements of the array which are equal to p?

Edit:- I think I should mention this, this question has been inspired from a Brilliant computer science problem.

Comment: you can use `list(set(myarray))` but it will rearrange the array so that it is in alphabetical/numerical order.

Comment: @The-IT I don't see how that is relevant to my question.

Comment: If you do that, you will find that all duplicates in the new list will be removed.

`list(set([2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6, 5]))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: @The-IT Thank you! I did not think of it that way. :)

Comment: Yeh, I just reread my comment and realized it was worded really badly. My bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to build a replacement list, where all elements are *not* equal to `p`:

```
a = [i for i in a if i != p]
```

Note that in Python, the datatype is called a `list`, not an array.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I am just a beginner to python, and I am more used to java, that's why I used the word 'array' instead of 'list'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter).

```
>>> a= [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> filter(lambda x: x != 2, a)
[1, 3, 1, 3]
```

In a function :

```
>>> def removeAll(inList, num):
        return filter(lambda elem: elem != num, inList)

>>> removeAll(a, 2)
[1, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Just a comment: afaik `filter`, `map` etc. return iterators in python 3. But correct me if I'm wrong…

Comment: List Comprehensions are more readable (although `map` may be a bit faster in some cases), but I just wanted to provide an alternative functional approach to the problem.

Comment: Yes of course, alternatives are great! It was just a comment. I edited it btw. (I meant those builtins don't behave the same in future python versions).

Comment: Can you please explain what is the function of the command 'lambda' here? 

Thanks for contributing, but a much simpler answer has already been posted. Anyways, I prefer remembering the alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: This link should be helpful - http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk